# Correlation with non-normal distribution

Tags: correlation, spss, nonparametric, kruskal-wallis-test

I want to find the correlation between a continous variable with a non normal distribution, positively skewed, and a categorical variable with 4 categories. The only test I can find that fits these variable is the kruskal wallis test, but I am not sure how I can use this test to find the correlation or relationship between my two variables. Can anyone suggest how this relates to correlation or another test to use with my data? Rookie with statistics, so please let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: I believe this question has already been answered by myself and John here:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69810/correlation-between-vegetation-and-erosion/69818#69818  In that question erosion was a continuous variable while vegetation was a categorical variable

Comment: Thanks BabakP, I did see that answer but wasnt sure if it was applicable to my questions as my continuous variable doesn't have a normal distributiom. Please correct me, as I thought ANOVA was used as a parametric alternative to a KW test?

Comment: You are correct that KW test is used as the nonparametric equivalent of the one-way ANOVA test, however, the explanation given for the box-plots by myself will work even if the response is non-normal.  I believe John's response all does not rely on normality even though he mentions the ANOVA test.

Comment: Thanks BabakP, I think the boxplot idea would be great for my project. Also, could you tell me if there an advantage to using John's ANOVA test over KW?

Comment: I think the use of ANOVA over Kruskal Wallis Test is another question entirely on its own.  If it has not already been asked before I would suggest posting it as another question.